# Exporting offset setting?

Tags: adobe-indesign

For quite sometime I have wondered what the offset function does when exporting a pdf and what the settings should be.  I have been told by another designer to leave it at the same size as the bleed setting.  What does this function effect and what are typical settings?
[image]

Comment: You could have easily figured this out. The `Offset` settings inside "Marks" offsets all the printer marks. You also could have tested this yourself fairly quickly.

Comment: You could have easily not replied, I was asking about setting and how this effected the document

Comment: I wasn't giving you an answer. I commented just to point out that you  could have figured out by youself in a minute or two. Use your smarts. It's  more rewarding.

Comment: I have tried and saw the results, my question what is the functionality and  if the values should be the same as the bleed.  I would rather not test it out when I send a $3000 ad to the printers.  Also I thought this was a forum for questions related to design and  programs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offset setting determines where all of the other printer's marks will be placed, in relation to the bleed marks.

Setting the offset to the same value as your bleed will ensure that the printer's marks are not placed anywhere inside of the bleed.  This not only looks better but is a better option, because it keeps the bleed clean, in my opinion.

Zero offset:

[image: zero]

Matched offset:

[image: matched]